# Azure run from package (.zip) with parameters

Tags: azure, arguments, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I've found a way to [run a dotnet app from a zip file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package).
My .zip only contains the build output of a regular `dotnet build` (an `.exe` and several `.dll`s).

My task is to pass an argument to the `.exe` file. I don't see any options neither on Azure Portal, nor on Kudu. Is there a way to run an Azure Web App from package with parameters? Thanks.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information for us to be able to help you. My initial reaction would be to use [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common) to enable you to configure how the application runs. If that doesn't suit your needs, please refer to [ask] and update your question.

Comment: @rickvdbosch actually I need to configure which parameters to run an `.exe` with. Like:
`application.exe -param 123`, but not Application Settings. It seems like by default a `dotnet run` is executed. But I need to configure the run arguments

Comment: The article you linked to is titled _Run your app in Azure App Service_, so you're running an App Service. Which hosts a website. Please explain what it is you're trying to achieve. I think there might be better alternatives available.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I have a .zip archive with an .exe file (which is the entry point) and a .dll for the app to work. I deploy this zip, and it runs automatically by Azure. My problem is that this .exe accepts several arguments, but I can't pass them, since it's Azure who runs the app, not me. I'm trying to find a way to pass parameters to this .exe

Comment: Please refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app)